# Owl Carousel wont scrolling on mobile view?

Tags: owl-carousel-2

Hello i have a problem with my website, i cant scrolling on owl-carousel div using mobile view.
Please check [My Website](https://sipadvocat.co.id/) Im stuck.

thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add following CSS to your owl-carousel's class. This worked for me

```
.overlay{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve the root of the problem, it simply allows you to scroll that element, but then you have a scrollbar inside of an element that should be scrolling anyway, and unless you specifically click the scrollbar and slide, it will attempt to scroll the owl-carousel items and not the container inside.